# Bootstrap: navigation and content won't detect mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've just downloaded the Bootstrap framework and have built a simple page with minimal changes to the CSS, following along with a PHP academy tutorial. I'm finding that on my desktop, the windows resize according to the framework's responsive features.  But on mobile, it simply reproduces a desktop version--no mobile menu, no responsive content, even with this meta tag in the head:

```
    <meta name-"viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

A responder on a similar post recommended this instead:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

But for me, this hasn't worked either.

Comment: this question is not satisfactory which we can find a solution to your problem. Please give more details.

Comment: What would you like to know?  The viewport command simply doesn't work when the default CSS is still intact.  That's all I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding this full line fixed the issue.  The website now resizes and pulls up the mobile menu:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;">
```